# Choosing an Android layout with consideration to performance

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout

How does your choice of layout (`LinearLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`, etc..) impact the performance of your application?

To be more specific:

- Will having one layout over another show a noticeable difference when the amount of `View` items in the layout approaches a high number?
- Can having a specific layout impact performance **after** every `View` has been inflated on an `Activity`?
- if you are developing for a specific display setting, Is there any benefit in assigning absolute coordinates to `View`, as opposed to using layout constraints?

Edit: Replaced all "Component" with "View", as this is Android, and not Swing.

Comment: The second overhead is the hyerarchy while calling draw(Canvas) and invalidate(), I dont think how bad can it be

Comment: Static views are rarely a problem. Where you encounter issues is with animations (scrolling lists, swiping pages, etc.). On the whole, I tend to view worrying about this up front as "premature optimization". Write what works. Tune the UI when the UI shows problems (e.g., dropped frames when animating).